# Trouble installing ejabberd on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, ejabberd

When I try to install ejabberd on ubuntu, it removes the erlang installed previously. Thus I'm not able to compile any erl files.

I had installed erlang-els. After installing ejabberd, trying to again install erlang gives error about dependancy trees.

Need help to get both, ejabberd and erlang installed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ejabberd binary installer from ProcessOne. It comes prepackaged, preconfigured, with its own Erlang. See this download page: https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

It removes erlang-els and will recommend erlang. Didn't see that. So Erlang works but erlang-els will get uninstalled.